# Extract floating point numbers from a delimited string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, floating-point, text-parsing, text-extraction

I would like to convert a string of delimited dimension values into floating numbers.

For example

```
152.15 x 12.34 x 11mm
```

into

```
152.15, 12.34 and 11
```

and store in an array such that:

```
$dim[0] = 152.15;
$dim[1] = 12.34;
$dim[2] = 11;
```

I would also need to handle scenarios where the delimiting text is different and the numbers may be followed by a unit expression like:

```
152.15x12.34x11 mm

152.15mmx12.34mm x 11mm
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$str = '152.15 x 12.34 x 11mm';
preg_match_all('!\d+(?:\.\d+)?!', $str, $matches);
$floats = array_map('floatval', $matches[0]);
print_r($floats);
```

The `(?:...)` regular expression construction is what's called a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). What that means is that chunk isn't separately returned in part of the `$mathces` array. This isn't strictly necessary **in this case** but is a useful construction to know.

**Note:** calling [`floatval()`](https://www.php.net/floatval) on the elements isn't strictly necessary either as PHP will generally juggle the types correctly if you try and use them in an arithmetic operation or similar. It doesn't hurt though, particularly for only being a one liner.

Comment: You can ditch the outer parentheses, and then $matches[0] will contain the matches. Also, what's the purpose of `?:` ?

Comment: You're quite right about the outer parentheses. Changed that. ?: makes whats inside those parentheses as a non-capturing group, meaning it wont separately be put in the $matches array anywhere, which it would be if you didnt include it. Not strictly necessary but cleaner and in more complicated examples may be necessary.

Comment: @cletus: You're absolutely right about the non-capturing parenthesis, but it makes the regex way less readable imo. I "get" Paolo's regex much faster then yours.

Comment: Well, look on the bright side: you learnt something extra. :) Non-capturing groups are useful.

Comment: Also, I read mine and its clear that I'm not interested in separately capturing parts of the number, just the whole number. The above clearly matches your intent, which is what you should be striving for imho.

Comment: It might be useful to also cast $matches[0] results as (float)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, cletus. For some reason, I didn't know about non-capturing groups. Now I do.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

$s = "152.15 x 12.34 x 11mm";

if (preg_match_all('/\d+(\.\d+)?/', $s, $matches)) {
    $dim = $matches[0];
}

print_r($dim);

?>
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => 152.15
    [1] => 12.34
    [2] => 11
)
```

Comment: that's true... corrected. at first i was printing out each value.  if $dim already has some values, we either use a loop or array_merge()

Comment: This answer is deceiving.  The output array values are strings, not floats.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '152.15 x 12.34 x 11mm';
preg_match_all('/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]); // Array ( [0] => 152.15 [1] => 12.34 [2] => 11 )
```

Comment: This answer is deceiving.  The output array values are strings, not floats.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "152.15 x 12.34 x 11mm";
$str = str_replace("mm", "", $str);
$str = explode("x", $str);
print_r($str); // Array ( [0] => 152.15 [1] => 12.34 [2] => 11 )
```

Tested it and it works on all strings above.

Comment: This answer is deceiving.  The output array values are strings, not floats.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sscanf()` affords the same level of required flexibility as a `preg_` function call, but `sscanf()` is better because it allows you to explicitly cast the targeted values as floats from its `format` parameter.

`%f` means a float number substring and `%*[mx ]` matches and silently ignores the unwanted separators.

Now there is no need to call `floatval()` within `array_map()` to cast the float values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/focug))

```
var_dump(
    sscanf($test, '%f%*[mx ]%f%*[mx ]%f')
);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  float(152.15)
  [1]=>
  float(12.34)
  [2]=>
  float(11)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/\d*\.?\d+|\d+/", "152.15mmx12.34mm x .11mm", $matches);
```

This example supports numbers like *.11* as well, since they are valid numbers. `$matches[0]` will contain *152.15*, *12.34* and *0.11*, given that you type cast the result to float. If you don't *0.11* will appear as *.11*. I would type cast using `array_map`.

```
$values = array_map("floatval", $matches[0]);
```

You can use the values for anything math without type casting them though. casting is just needed when printing them directly.

Comment: Your example would be clearer if you used the sample data from the question.