# In Php, how to get float value from a mixed string?

Tags: php, string

I got a string like:

```
$str = "CASH55.35inMyPocket";
```

I want to get **55.35** only.

I tried:

```
$str = floatval("CASH55.35inMyPocket");
if ($str > 0) {
    echo "Greater_Zero";
} else {
    echo "LessZERO!!";
}
// echo "LessZERO!!";
```

I also tried:

```
$str = (float)"CASH55.35inMyPocket";
if ($str > 0) {
    echo "Greater_Zero";
} else {
    echo "LessZERO!!";
}
// echo "LessZERO!!";
```

According to the Documentation:

> Strings will most likely return `0` although this depends on the
>   leftmost characters of the string.

So, `flotval` and `(float)` apparently only work if the string is something like:
`55.35aAbBcCdDeEfF`... but will NOT work if it is like: `aAbBcC55.35dDeEfF`

is there a way to get the float ***no matter the position of text?***

Comment: Probably you have to use `preg_match`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract floating point numbers from a string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/944400)

Comment: NO DUPPLICATE: The question there, the `string` begins with `Number`... in my question the `string` **does not have to start with a number**...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you dont want to use regular expressions use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
$str = "CASH55.35inMyPocket";
var_dump( (float) filter_var( $str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION ) ); // float(55.35)
```

Comment: Thanks for the `(float)`... without it, the returned value is a string

Comment: Please can you explain the `"FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION"` part?.... can't seem to understand why it is required other than having the `"FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT"` alone.... thx

Comment: FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION is what I was looking for. thank

Comment: @UniversalGrasp this flag allows to have numbers after the decimal. If no flag, it will remove the `.` and shows `5535` in this case

Answer (score 5):

What you have cannot be casted to a float, because it doesn't look like a float from PHP's perspective. It is possible to grab the value using regex though.

If you are not sure whether there will always be a decimal. And you are trying to get the number regardless of position in the text (as per your question). You could use:

```
^.*?([\d]+(?:\.[\d]+)?).*?$
```

Which gets the numeric values from the following strings:

```
CASH55.35inMyPocket
CASH55inMyPocket
55.35inMyPocket
55inMyPocket
inMyPocket55.35
inMyPocket55
```

Explanation: http://regex101.com/r/tM8eM0
Demo: http://rubular.com/r/Gw5HTzsejj
PHP demo: https://eval.in/165521

Basically it looks for numbers in the string. And optionally it also check for decimals after that.

Comment: Is this probably the Fastest way on earth?

Comment: in Performance. Compared to the other answers, Yours seems shorter and just wondering if it is also Faster... thx

Comment: I don't know whether it is faster. Neither do I really care unless you are doing this thousands and thousands times throughout the request

Answer (score 4):

I think a `preg_replace` could be helpfull here (untested):

```
$float = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/', "", "CASH55.35inMyPocket"); // only show the numbers and dots
```

You could extend the preg a little more to only get [number].[number], but in this case I think it will work.

Comment: Not helpful in case if it is .CASH55.35inMyPocket => .55.35

Comment: Note: if you change string to: "CASH.55.35inMyPocket", or ".CASH55.35inMyPocket" (see leading dot) and this solution fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a little Function to extract that value for you before using either `floatval` or `(float)`.

Something like:

```
function myFloats($str) {

  if(preg_match("#([0-9\.]+)#", $str, $match)) { // search for number that may contain '.'
    return floatval($match[0]);
  } else {
    return floatval($str); // take some last chances with floatval
  }
}
```

then test:

```
echo myFloats("CASH55.35inMyPocket");
```

Comment: This would also match `3.3.3` or `...`

Comment: The answer is perfect for: `CASH55.35inMyPocket`

Comment: @ErickBest Answer like this - and especially your defensive comment - could cost you your 'dream job', as recruiters do sample Stack. You'd be probably branded something like: unimaginative coder, cannot anticipate real life scenarios, writes rigid code etc. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex:

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', 'CASH55.35inMyPocket', $matches);
$number = (float) $matches[1]; // 55.35
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @hek2mgl answer to get both float and integer numbers

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+\.?[0-9].)/', 'CASH55.35inMyPocket', $matches);
$number = (float) $matches[1]; // 55.35

preg_match('/([0-9]+\.?[0-9].)/', 'CASH55inMyPocket', $matches);
$number = (float) $matches[1]; // 55

preg_match('/([0-9]+\.?[0-9].)/', 'Total.CASH55.35inMyPocket', $matches);  //with a dot before number
$number = (float) $matches[1]; // 55.35
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function extract_numbers($string)
{
preg_match_all('/([\d]+)/', $string, $match);
return $match[0];
}
```