# Extract positive and negative floating point numbers from a string in php

Tags: php, regex, floating-point, negative-number

For a php I have to extract floating point numbers from a string. I'm new to regex, but I found a solution which works for me in most cases:

[Extract floating point numbers from a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944400/extract-floating-point-numbers-from-a-string-in-php)

```
$str = '152.15 x 12.34 x 11mm';
preg_match_all('!\d+(?:\.\d+)?!', $str, $matches);
$floats = array_map('floatval', $matches[0]);
print_r($floats);
```

Only problem are negative values; can somebody change the expression for me in a way that negative numbers are also included properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

This should do it for you.

```
$re = "/-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?/m"; 
$str = "4.321 -3.1212"; 
$subst = "coach"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me 'Warning: preg_match_all(): No ending delimiter '-' found' unfortunately...

Comment: still not working...test string would be something like "numbers are -3.026 and 5.65 or 6525K" and I'm looking for an array with -3.026, 5.65 and 6525 in it....same thing as the function above in the link does, just with keeping the "-" sign.